# Error: cannot find module vite, react, react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, typescript, module, yarnpkg, vite

#### Error

I use `yarn create vite` command to create a `react-ts` app and `vite` as the building tool. After `yarn add` install the packages, in `vite.config.ts` file:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
```

It gives erros: **cannot find module 'vite', cannot find module '@vitejs/plugin-react'**. It also appears when I trying to import `react, react-router-dom` in tsx file. But I am already used `yarn install` to install all the dependencies that are mentioned in `package.json` file(I also tried `yarn add`, didn't work).

#### Tried Solutions

I tried the following solutions and none of these completely solve the problem:

- use `npm install / yarn add` the modules that are missing

the error still there.

- create a file `xxx.d.ts` then declare the modules are missing and `include xxx.d.ts` in the `ts.config`.

it can solve the missing module thing but `useState` and other functions give error.

Though the error is reported by VS Code, **but the project can running and it works**. So I am wondering if the error relates to config file or ESLint.

#### file

Here is my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "client",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.22",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.39",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.33",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.10",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^1.0.7",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "vite": "^2.8.0"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

`tsconfig.node.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}
```

Comment: I am getting the same problem but only after doing yarn install, it works with npm install though

Answer (score 1):

1. delete the 'node_modules' folder
2. yarn (or npm) install

I couldn't get the Node Modules folder back after 'yarn'
and I needed to add a file .yarnrc.yml containing "  nodeLinker: node-modules  "
After that again yarn (or npm) install

That worked for me.

Answer (score -8):

Not exactly the same problem I encounter.

But either, try to install `vite` globally.

But the best option, will be to uninstall your current `node` version (and clean the global `node_modules`...), then install the latest `node` version, actually node `17`.